# SonarQube jenkins job fails with "Fail to execute request"

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-4.5

We are running SonarQube 4.5.1 and run the analyzes on project with Jenkins and the SonarQube Plugin.
Starting three days ago we encounter the following error message on a few of our jobs.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) on project MYPROJECT: Fail to execute request [code=500, url=https://SONARQUBE/batch/project?key=com.myplugins.sonar.plugins:MYPROJECT&amp;preview=false]: Fail to download [https://SONARQUBE/batch/project?key=com.myplugins.sonar.plugins:MYPROJECT&amp;preview=false]. Response code: 500 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) on project MYPROJECT: Fail to execute request [code=500, url=https://SONARQUBE/batch/project?key=com.myplugins.sonar.plugins:MYPROJECT&amp;preview=false]

Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Fail to execute request [code=500, url=https://SONARQUBE/batch/project?key=com.myplugins.sonar.plugins:MYPROJECT&amp;preview=false]

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to execute request [code=500, url=https://SONARQUBE/batch/project?key=com.myplugins.sonar.plugins:MYPROJECT&amp;preview=false]

Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.HttpDownloader$HttpException: Fail to download [https://SONARQUBE/batch/project?key=com.myplugins.sonar.plugins:MYPROJECT&amp;preview=false]. Response code: 500
```

If I copy the URL to my browser I get the message:

> "You're only authorized to execute a local (dry run) SonarQube analysis without pushing the results to the SonarQube server. Please contact your SonarQube administrator."

Setting &preview=true (out of curiosity) shows this message:

> "Expected one result (or null) to be returned by selectOne(), but found: 2"

There were no changes on code or settings.

The projects are listed twice in the projects overview but link to the same project dashboard (same key, same measures, etc.)

"Bulk deletion" shows no duplicates and they are not listed under the "Ghost" tab either.

We also took a look at the database and executed following statement:

```
SELECT * FROM projects where kee=MYPROJECT-KEY
```

still no duplications found.

We've never encountered a similiar problem and are completely clueless. Any advice?

Comment: Deleting the SQ Project and restarting the jenkins job fixed the problem. I'm still curious about the cause...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the last successful analyse left two snapshots in the database... Cause is unknown.

```
mysql> SELECT rootProject.* , s.islast, s.id    FROM projects p     INNER JOIN snapshots s ON s.project_id=p.id AND s.islast=true INNER JOIN projects rootProject ON rootProject.id=s.root_project_id AND p.kee='PROJECTKEY';
+-------+---------------------------------------------------+---------+-------+-----------+------------+---------+----------+------------------+-----------+-----------+---------------------+------+------------------------------------+--------+----------+
| id    | name | description                                | enabled | scope | qualifier | kee        | root_id | language | copy_resource_id | long_name | person_id | created_at          | path | deprecated_kee                     | islast | id       |
+-------+---------------------------------------------------+---------+-------+-----------+------------+---------+----------+------------------+-----------+-----------+---------------------+------+------------------------------------+--------+----------+
| 12814 | NAME | DESC                                       |       1 | PRJ   | TRK       | PROJECTKEY |    NULL | NULL     |             NULL | NAME      |      NULL | 2014-07-08 16:57:46 | NULL | PROJECTKEY                         |      1 | 21507844 |
| 12814 | NAME | DESC                                       |       1 | PRJ   | TRK       | PROJECTKEY |    NULL | NULL     |             NULL | NAME      |      NULL | 2014-07-08 16:57:46 | NULL | PROJECTKEY                         |      1 | 21516010 |
+-------+---------------------------------------------------+---------+-------+-----------+------------+---------+----------+------------------+-----------+-----------+---------------------+------+------------------------------------+--------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT rootProject.id , s.islast, s.id, s.build_date    FROM projects p     INNER JOIN snapshots s ON s.project_id=p.id AND s.islast=true INNER JOIN projects rootProject ON rootProject.id=s.root_project_id AND p.kee='PROJECTKEY';
+-------+--------+----------+---------------------+
| id    | islast | id       | build_date          |
+-------+--------+----------+---------------------+
| 12814 |      1 | 21507844 | 2015-10-25 02:21:59 |
| 12814 |      1 | 21516010 | 2015-10-25 02:21:59 |
+-------+--------+----------+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Deleting the SonarQube Project is the only solution (deleting the database entry results in a different error)

Comment: Delete the project doesn't fix my issue. I have AD groups to control the access, e.g. sonarqube_users, and give this group able to provision projects in SQ, then add all service accounts running Jenkins slave to this group. I notice these service accounts are not listed inside SQ users, because they never logged in. Could this be an issue?

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I run sonar as service, when I run in from command prompt as administrator, every thing works fine.